# PHPUnit configuration

Tags: php, apache2, phpunit

I have to install and configure PHPUnit.
I have installed it with pear and now I have to configure `include_path` inside `php.ini` because if I launch this command inside my console:

```
phpunit version
```

return me this error:

```
Warning: require_once(File/Iterator/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'File/Iterator/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /usr/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

I don't want to set all path in absolute.
I have check inside my system and I have find some file inside `/usr/share/pear`, then I have tried:

```
include_path =".:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/usr/share/pear"

include_path =".:/usr/share/pear"

include_path=".:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear"

include_path=".:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear:/usr/share/pear"

include_path=".:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/pear"
```

Any of this include_path work if i laungh `phpunit version` same error. Obviously every time that I change my `php.ini` file I restart my apache server.

How can I solve this problem?

I have seen many question/answer but no one resolve my problem.

I'm using XAMPP in a mac with Mavericks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problem with phpunit can't find `/etc/php.ini` configuration file.
It's necessary just create symbolic link.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini
```